# Unable to run git commands with crontab

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, cron, git-fetch

I am setting up a server, and I want the git repository in my server to be up to date with the origin server(Github). I tried to run a cron job which updates the repository in the server every minute. This was successful in my mac pc.

crontab:

```
* * * * * bash /home/ubuntu/venv/App/deployer.bash >> /home/ubuntu/venv/App/Logs/deployer.txt 2>&1
```

Here is the part that fails in the server:

```
git fetch --all 
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Error :

```
Fetching origin
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin
```

Everything works fine outside the crontab.
 For example :
I Can do all git commands within the git repo without sudo.
Using sudo I get the same error as in cronjob.

Update :

Figured out what caused the problem:

2>&1 in the crontab expression was writing the standard error and it was very correct. 
When I ran the commands outside of crontab it never requested for authentication. But on crontab on every execution, the commands are requesting for an authentication

Now can anyone explain why this would cause an error like that?

Comment: I believe you have authentication problem. You need to configure crontab to use for example SSL authentication

Comment: I think you run the commands in cron under a different user from what you do in the command line hence the authentication problem. Either run the commands in cron under the same user or configure ssh keys for the cron user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the ssh key to the ssh-agent every time before executing the git command worked. This is what I did.

I added the below command in the cronjob :

```
eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa && ssh-add -l
git fetch --all && sleep 2s && git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: An alternative is to use deploy keys: 
https://gist.github.com/zhujunsan/a0becf82ade50ed06115